# Subclassing causing bad memory access, how should properties be structured

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a super class 'Node' and several sub classes e.g. 'SubNode1', 'SubNode2' etc.

I need to have a property which all the sub classes need called 'parentNode'.  It gets set when init is called on 'SubNode1' and the object is passed through of type 'Node'.  The reason I used a sub class is because these objects are comforming to a protocol and I cannot use the sub class each time - I need to pass 'Node' around.

What I don't know is how to structure my objects.  Where should the release be and where should the property be and should it be retain as I constantly get exe_bad_access errors because of this.

This is how I have structured it currently:

**Node.h**

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) Node *parentNode;
```

**Node.m**

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [parentNode release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

**SubNode1.h**

```
@interface SubNode1 : Node
{
    // No reference to parentNode property
}
```

**SubNode1.m**

```
- (id)initWithParentNode:(SubNode1 *)theParentNode {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        super.parentNode = theParentNode;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already designing it the correct way. The error is probably that:

```
super.parentNode = theParentNode;
```

should be:

```
self.parentNode = theParentNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

initWithParentNode should be *defined* in Node:

```
- (id) initWithParentNode: (Node *) parentNode_ {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.parentNode = parentNode_ ;
        ...
    }
}
```

and *called from* SubNode:

```
- (id) initWithParentNode: (Node *) parentNode_ {
    if ((self = [super initWithParentNode: parentNode_])) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed nicer style, but is there a way the original version would cause memory problems and this would fix it that I'm missing? Getting too used to ARC, apparently :)